# WebView.addJavascriptInterface: passing Java arrays to JS

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, webview

I have an object in Java, with a method, annotated with `@JavaInterface`. When I try to return an array, say, String[], the result is exposed to JS as `undefined`.

I'd like to be able to pass at least iterable objects, no matter what type wrapped in, but have no idea how to implement [Symbol.Iterator], as it's a *property*, and they couldn't be passed.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, the result is NOT exposed to JS as `undefined`. In fact, the value depends on what type the Java method returns. If it's `Object`, the result is an empty non-iterable object.

Java:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public Object foo(String p1, String p2)
{
    return new String[]{"a","b","c"};
}
```

JS:

```
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames(catalogItems): ' +
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(catalogItems));

for (let item of catalogItems)
{
    text += item.text;
}
```

Log:

```
D/WebView: catalogItems: [object Object] -- From line 18 of file:///android_asset/content.html
D/WebView: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(catalogItems):  -- From line 23 of file:///android_asset/content.html
D/WebView: Uncaught TypeError: catalogItems[Symbol.iterator] is not a function -- From line 28 of file:///android_asset/content.html
```

If the method returns `String[]`:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String[] foo(String p1, String p2)
{
    return new String[]{"a","b","c"};
}
```

it seems the method just is not being called at all.